# logging into Visual Studio Team Services using developer command prompt - can't delete project

Tags: azure-devops, team-project

I want to tidy up my Visual Studio Team Services source control and I am trying to delete an old project. I've looked online and I have the command required for the developer command prompt. However I don't know how to authenticate myself via the prompt.

For example I have this command:

```
tfsdeleteproject /collection/https://DOMAIN_NAME.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/PROJECT_NAME/
```

But I get this message:

```
Deletes the team project from Team Foundation. To use this command, you must be a member of either the Team Foundation Server Administrators group or a member of the Project Administrators group for the project you are deleting. Use this command with caution because after deleting the team project it cannot be recovered.
```

Can anyone provide some help? I usually access source control via the tfs plugin in visual studio and this has a username and password screen. But for the command prompt I don't know how to login.

Comment: It normally uses your Windows Domain Authentication, you don't need to enter them. If you are an admin (you haven't stated), you can also delete Team Projects from the Web Access (VSO) / TF Admin Console (on-prem).

Answer (score 2):

As @DaveShaw mentioned, to delete a team project on Visual Studio Team Services, use the web access administration page (https://YOUR-SITE.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_admin). Click the small arrow by the name of the obsolete team project and Delete.

[image: delete vso team project]